# Attack coastal provinces with ships?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I've just started my first game as the Ottomans, and my 10 regiment army is taking a long time to conquer Albania, so I sent some Light Ships, Galleys and Cogs over to help. They are in the sea next to the province, but I can't figure out how to have them support the siege or attack the one enemy ship present.

I selected the Light Ships and clicked the Detach Blockade button, but that didn't seem to change anything. The image of the city on the siege popup shows it's a port city if that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: **You can't.**

Ships in EU4 are not able to attack provinces, neither are they able to attack enemy ships that lie in the harbor of a city/province.

What you can do is **blockade the harbor** of the enemy city, so that other ships cannot enter or leave. This greatly improves your chances for a shorter siege by land troops on this coastal province.

The rationale behind this is that if your troops are besieging a city on the coast, the defenders could get support (food, water, supplies) through incoming ships. So a coastal province automatically gets a bonus on defense if you do not block the harbor with your ships. You can see this bonus on the siege screen. (Screenshot will follow.)

A coastal province **automatically** gets blockaded if you have ships in the adjacent water region where the city's harbor lies. (given that you are at war with the province owner)
So it is always a good idea to blockade the harbors of enemies provinces you want to conquer.

Also it should be noted that blockading provinces gives you additional warscore.

---

The *Detach Blockade* button will split a troop from your ship squad that is large enough to blockade a harbor. It works pretty much equal to the *Detach Siege* button of land troops.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it also takes a certain level of diplomatic technology before blockading is possible.

Comment: Also of note is that occupying a naval province will cause enemy ships to leave the dock (since now, for all intents and purposes, it's *your* dock), which means they can be attacked and scuttled by your blockading navy.